# Proof-Verification:$\left|\int_0^1 f(x)dx\right|\leq \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 |f'(x)|dx.$

Tags: integration, proof-verification, definite-integrals

## Problem

Let $f(x)$ be a function with $f'(x)$ continuous over $[0,1]$. $f(0)+f(1)=0$. Prove $$\left|\int_0^1 f(x)dx\right|\leq \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 |f'(x)|dx.$$

## Proof

Let $x-1/2=t$，then $x=t+1/2$，$dx=dt$. Thus
\begin{align*}
\left|\int_0^1 f(x)dx\right|&=\left|\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{~~\frac{1}{2}} f\left(t+\frac{1}{2}\right)dt\right|\\
&=\left|\left[tf\left(t+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right]_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{~~\frac{1}{2}}-\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{~~\frac{1}{2}} tf'\left(t+\frac{1}{2}\right)dt\right|~~~&\textrm{integrating by parts}\\
&=\left|0-\int_{0}^{1} \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)f'\left(x\right)dx\right|~~~&\textrm{substituting $t+1/2=x$}\\
&\leq\int_0^1   \left|\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)f'\left(x\right)\right|dx\\
&\leq \left|\xi-\frac{1}{2}\right|\int_0^1 |f'(x)|dx~~~&\textrm{applying the first MVT for integral}\\
&\leq \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 |f'(x)|dx,
\end{align*}
which is desired.

Comment: Seems correct. You can directly use $1$ instead of $\xi$.

Answer (score 5):

Your proof is correct. For the last few lines I propose this variation:
$$\begin{align}\dots&\leq\int_0^1   \left|\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)f'\left(x\right)\right|dx\\
&= \int_0^1 \underbrace{\left|\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right|}_{\leq 1/2}|f'(x)|dx\\
&\leq \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 |f'(x)|dx.\end{align}$$
In this way we avoid the application of MVT.

Comment: Good idea! Thanks!